# VBA Collection.Add Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection to get the unique values from an array, but for some reason it goes through the array but the collection ultimately shows with

the code for the collection is:

```
Dim Materials as Variant
Dim Unique as New Collection, a

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In Materials
    Unique.Add a, a
Next
```

Can anyone offer insight why this wouldn't work?

Comment: What values are stored in `a`?  Shouldn't the key value of a collection be a string, so if `a` is a number you'll get a type-mismatch, but the `On Error Resume Next` hides that.  Try `Unique.Add a,CSTR(a)`.  Saying that though - the code you've posted doesn't actually assign any values to `Materials` which makes it hard to test the problem (you could be assigning form controls to Materials for all I know).

Comment: You see `On Error Resume Next` in code by people who should know better so Newbies copy them. It means: if there is an error don't bother to tell me and carry on regardless. Remove it and see if you get an error message.

Comment: As defined `Materials` is a Variant.  You can place an array in it with something like: `Materials = Array(x , y, z)`.  Do you?

Comment: You say " ... collection to get the unique values  ..."  Without more information it is difficult to say but I suspect you want a Dictionary.  I have never tried using keys with a Collection but I did not think they had to be unique. Typically you access a Collection by position and a Dictionary by key.

Comment: A `Dictionary` is a more natural choice than a collection here. Much more flexible.

Comment: sorry, Materials is a list of numbers so that looks to be part of the issue
Unique.add a, CSTR(a) now works to collect the values, however once I've looped through all the values in Materials I have 256 values in the collection, but collection.count is 418?

Comment: How about making a minimal complete verifiable example? We can't reproduce your issue as is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a collection (since, e.g., you want to keep the items in the order in which they first appear) it is still a good idea to use a dictionary as a temp data structure while building up the collection. Something like:

```
Function Uniques(A As Variant) As Collection
    Dim D As Object, C As New Collection
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In A
        If Not D.exists(v) Then
            D.Add v, 1
            C.Add v
        End If
    Next v

    Set Uniques = C
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Materials As Variant, C As Collection, v As Variant
    Materials = Array(2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2)
    Set C = Uniques(Materials)
    For Each v In C
        Debug.Print v
    Next v
End Sub
```

Output:

```
2 
3 
5 
6 
7 
4
```

If all you want is a set-like object rather than a collection per-se, you could skip the collection completely and just have `Uniques()` (suitably modified) return the dictionary itself.